# Why are edits not presented to posters for review before they are approved

Tags: discussion

It is frustrating to get a notice that your question has been reviewed and some questionable substitution approved, and you were not even aware that your question was even being considered for editing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to [the points noted by fredsbend](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3782/30) I'll add a couple of notes on how the system is implemented:

1. There are two kinds of edits: suggested edits and edits.

   - Suggested edits can be done by anybody (even anonymous non-users), but they have to be approved by at least 2 high-rep members of the community. Anybody below 2k rep can only make these kind of edits. The changes do not appear immediately.
   - Once someone reaches 2k rep it is assumed that they have been around long enough to know generally how the system works and they are trusted to both make immediate edits.
2. In both cases, as the original author you are notified.

   - In the case of suggested edits you are notified that an edit has been suggested and, as the author of the post, you can approve or reject the edit unilaterally. If you don't catch this before other reviewers do, it takes 2 voters from the rest of the community to approve an edit.
   - In the case of normal edits, you are notified that one of your posts has been changed. The revision history is available to show exactly what they changed.
3. In both cases, edits are subject to review.

   fredsbend covered this, but it bears repeating: all edits bump posts back to the home  page for community  review.
4. All edits can be rolled back. Whether you are the post owner or just reviewing and edit to some other post, checking the revision history for any post will reveal "rollback" links on each previous revision and at your discretion you can revert to an earlier version.

   Here is how to access the revision history:

   - Click on the edited link above the user name that most recently edited at the bottom of the post.
   - That link is between your user name and the Share, edit, flag links.

   [image: edit link]

   And here is a sample that shows how you rollback a revision:

   - Once you click on the revision history link you will see all the revisions stacked on top of each other, starting with the most recent one.
   - You can click on the blue background to expand the text of previous revisions.
   - In the blue background of any previous revision are the links *source*, *edit*, and *rollback*. Clicking *rollback* changes the post exactly back to that particular revision.
     [image: rollback link]

Answer (score 7):

It's a reasonable question, but it comes from a misunderstanding.

Practically, yes, it is your post. You wrote it, your name is on it, and you get credit for it.

Theoretically, it is not really your post. It's not even SE's post. It is the community's post. It belongs to all of us equally and we all have equal right to submit peer reviewed edits. Here's why this theory of editing can work:

- All edits are easily seen and can be rolled back if necessary.
- Edits bump the post to the top of the active page, where pretty much every frequent user will see it. I personally check this regularly to make sure they are valid edits, and they almost always are.
- Edits from low rep users are sent to the review queue where two high rep users must approve it before it is made public. Then it is bumped too.
- The user who most recently edited is put at the bottom of the post right there with you, so there are no secret edits that someone should confuse with you having written.
- You can always roll it back.

So there is really little reason to worry that the post will be invalidly edited without you or someone else noticing.

However, you might just want to know when this is happening. I personally think that is reasonable, but I bet SE will not make that adjustment to the notification system. You can try, however, to see it they will, by posting a feature request on [Meta Stack Exchange.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) I searched and could not find this already existing, which surprised me.

Comment: just to make the licensing super clear, it's owned by the poster, but licensed in perpetuity to Stack Exchange under a non-revocable CC-by-SA license. See http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/ for more info.

Comment: @Fredsbend I have not had a rollback option  on any of the proposed edits to Christianity stack exchange posts, was given one for the edit to this post.

Comment: @Bye Rollback is an option that you can click after going in to the edit history which is enterable on the active link that describes the last edit.

Comment: @Bye In addition to what fredsbend has already answered, I would recommend you read [this section of the help](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/editing), which covers why people can edit your posts, and how it all works.

Comment: @Bye See [Caleb's answer](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/3784/3961) for how to rollback. He made snapshots.

Comment: @fredsbend I checked out Caleb's post shortly after he posted it. unfortunately my text to speech software is woefully inadequate for the snapshots, but hopefully with what I did elicit along with some personal research I will eventually understand the procedures. While I have a lot of reps I am relatively new to the site, being legally blind I miss a lot of the little things about the site that are quite obvious to sighted users. It takes me little longer to learn things, but in time I will get there. So please do not give up on me, I'm not stupid (even though it may appear that way).

Comment: @fredsbend Please do not perceive any animosity in my last comment, after rereading it I sensed that you could feel that I was abrading you, and nothing could have been further from my mind. Please accept my apologies for any misunderstanding arising from my comment.

Comment: @Bye No apology necessary. I did not know you were so poorly sighted. I will keep that in mind. Textual descriptions will help you the best.

Comment: @Bye I added textual descriptions of the snapshots to [Caleb's answer.](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/3784/3961)

Comment: @fredsbend Thanks I was not able get the part about the blue background. maybe now I can at least handle that problem.